# Global existence of $L^p$-solutions to a quasilinear diffusion equation

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, parabolic-pde

We consider the diffusion problem
$$\begin{cases} 
\partial_t u = \nabla \cdot (a(u)\nabla u), \quad t>0, x \in \mathbb{R}^n \\
u(0) = u_0
\end{cases}$$
for functions $u \colon [0,T] \times \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ and are interested in strong $L^p$-solutions for some $p \in (1,\infty)$, i.e. functions
$$u \in {H}^{1,p}((0,T);L^p(\mathbb{R}^n)) \cap L^p((0,T);L^p(\mathbb{R}^n)) \cap L^p((0,T);H^{2,p}(\mathbb{R}^n)) \cap C([0,T];B_{pp}^{2-2/p}(\mathbb{R}^n)).$$

Let $a \in C^2_b(\mathbb{R}^n;Sym(n))$ and $\langle a(z) \xi , \xi \rangle \ge  \lambda |\xi|^2 $ for all $z \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and any $\xi \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and $1-2/p>n/p$, i.e. $p>n+2$. Then, it is classical that for every $u_0 \in B_{pp}^{2-2/p}$ there exists a unique local in time $L^p$-solution of the diffusion problem. Indeed, this can be shown using the well-known maximal $L^p$-regularity for the frozen problem together with Banach's fixed point theorem.

I am interested if the constructed solutions does exist global in time, too. If we consider a bounded and smooth domain instead of $\mathbb{R}^n$ this can be shown by making use of the a priori Hölder and $L^\infty$ estimates for example. However, this does not work on $\mathbb{R}^n$.

My questions: Do you know any results concerning the global in time existence of $L^p$-solutions to above problem? Moreover, I am interested in references for whole space global in time existence results to similar problems, too.

Comment: Do you mean global existence for "small" initial data?

Comment: I not mean global existence for "small" initial datum exclusively but surely am interested in this kind of argument, too. Do you mean that the global existence result does only hold for small initial datum?

Comment: I do not know. Can you prove global existence in a bounded domain without assuming smallness on $u_0$. The only difference I seee between the bounded case and the whole space is the decay of the linear part.

Comment: Yes this can be proven. The argument, in a more general setting (fractional in time), can be found in section 5.3 of the article "Global strong solvability of a quasilinear subdiffusion problem, Rico Zacher". However, the proof continues to hold for the diffusion equation in question on a bounded domain. 

Unfortunately, the proof fails on an unbounded domain. The problem is smallness of the $L^p$-norm of the squared gradient of u.

Comment: I had a look at the paper. Which are the points where the boundedness of $\Omega$ is used? At first sight most of the arguments seem to be valid in the whole space, but I could have overlooked some points.

Comment: On page 828, the Gagliardo Nirenberg inequality is used to control the $L^p$-norm of the squared gradient of $u$. It is implicitly used that due to the a priori bound in the Hölder norm we also have an a priori bound on $u$ in some Sobolev norm $H^{\epsilon,q}$. Here, the proof fails on the whole space as $u \in C^\epsilon(\mathbb{R }^n)$ does not imply $u \in H^{\epsilon,q}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ in general.

Comment: In his notation, the function $u$ belongs to $H^2_p$ and is bounded in the sup-norm. By Gagiardo Nirenberg then $\nabla u \in H^1_{2p}$ and the interpolation inequality holds from which one should conclude, if I am not completely lost. He has also $p>N$ and so the embeddings he uses $H^2_p \subset H^1_{2p} \subset C^\alpha$ are true in the whole space.

Comment: Your argument would give an estimate of the form $\|{u} \|_{H^{1,2p}} \le \|{u} \|_{H^{2,p}}^{1/2} \|{u} \|_{L^\infty}^{1/2}$. However, we need to have a slightly better bound. This is why instead of $L^\infty$ the author uses a Sobolev space $H^{\epsilon,p}$ (the regularity provided by the priori Hölder bound). Thus, instead of the exponent $1/2$ he gets the exponent $\theta < 1/2$, which in turn is used to absorb the $H^{2,p}$ norm of $u$ at a later point.

Comment: I agree with your second point. But I am not sure how this does help. How would you deduce from the embeddings $H^{2,p} \hookrightarrow H^{1,2p} \hookrightarrow C^\epsilon$ that an interpolation inequality of the type $\|{u} \|_{H^{1,2p}} \le \|{u} \|_{H^{2,p}}^{\theta} \|{u} \|_{C^\epsilon}^{1-\theta}$ holds for some $\theta \in (0,1/2)$?

Comment: Moreover, the latter interpolation inequality can hold for $\theta <1/2$ only if $\epsilon = 0$ due to scaling reasons.

Comment: Let me see if I have understood. You say that for the interpolation inequality to hold with $\theta<1/2$ you need a Sobolev norm and this is controlled by a Holder norm if the set is bounded. Is this correct? By the way, did you ask Rico Zacher?

Comment: Yes, exactly. I have discussed this problem with Rico Zacher. He agrees that this particular argument does not work on $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: Thnk you, now I have understood where the problem is.